# Bash reading line by line. Unable to combine variable and string, variable is appended

Tags: bash

I'm getting some very strange behaviour that I can't figure out when trying to read a txt file.

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
98040520
98041022
98041024
...
```

And then I have a bash script with some basic debugging that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read id; do
    test=123
    echo "${test}.png"
    echo $id
    echo "${id}.png"
    echo "test${id}.png"
    exit
done <myfile.txt
```

And the output is

```
123.png
98040520
.png
.png98040520
```

What on earth is going on?

It prints "98040520" just fine, but it won't print "98040520.png", it just prints the ".png" part and an attempt to print "test98040520.png" results in the id being appended creating ".png98040520" and the word "test" excluded altogether!!

I figure it's got to be something to do with line endings (the txt file comes from windows) but I haven't been able to find anything online that will help. I've been searching for how to trim whitespace or line endings which may mean i've been looking for the wrong thing.

In case it's not clear what i'd like to do is get "98040520.png" or more specifically `filepath=../../path/to/my/dir/98040520.png` but what i've posted above is a simpler example of the problem I seem to be having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed a line-endings issue (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355559/bash-and-carriage-return-behavior) for an explanation of what the `\r` is doing to your terminal output).

You can either fix the endings in the file or fix them in the script (`tr -d "\r"` will remove all instances of `\r` to yield unix-style line endings in the text passed to the while loop):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat myfile.txt | tr -d "\r" | while read id; do
    test=123
    echo "${test}.png"
    echo $id
    echo "${id}.png"
    echo "test${id}.png"
    exit
done
```

Using the fixed version gives the expected output.

Comment: Thanks that does fix it, none of the other similar solutions worked for me. Would you mind clarifying what `tr -d "\r"` does?

Comment: I've added an explanation (it's removing the carriage returns so that you get UNIX style line-endings).

Answer (score -1):

All your quotes and curl brackets are not necessary. Also you have `exit` in your while loop, you should get rid of that:

```bash
while read id; do
    test=123
    echo $test.png
    echo $id
    echo $id.png
    echo test$id.png
done <myfile.txt
```

Comment: The curly brackets were just me trying to make it clearer, the same output will and does happen without it. And the exit is just because obviously I don't need to loop through them all to demonstrate the issue. Unfortunately your answer doesn't respond to the actual issue i'm having.

Comment: my code produces the following result, isn't that what you expected?

    123.png
    98040520
    98040520.png
    test98040520.png
    123.png
    98041022
    98041022.png
    test98041022.png
    123.png
    98041024
    98041024.png
    test98041024.png